# JavaScript - Módulo matemático de um valor

Tags: javascript, matemática

Existe algum comando (ou símbolo) que faz o módulo matemático de um valor?

Por exemplo: `var teste = |10|-|6|;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa sintaxe `|n|` não existe no JavaScript, pelo menos para esse propósito.

O que teria que fazer é usar `Math.abs()`. Exemplos:

```
var teste = Math.abs(10)-Math.abs(6); // 4
var teste = Math.abs(10-6); // 4
var teste = Math.abs(-10-6); // 16
var teste = Math.abs(-10-(-6)) // 4
```

> **Obs.:** Quando envolver operações matemáticas entre os valores, use `Math.abs()` para cada valor. Por exemplo:
>
> `Math.abs(10) - Math.abs(-6)` é diferente de `Math.abs(10-(-6))`. O
>   primeiro retorna `4` e o segundo `16`.

[Mais sobre Math.abs() no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

Comment: Entendi como funciona, obrigado @DvD, ótima explicação

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer a representação em módulo de um número. Veja [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

```js
console.log(Math.abs(10));
console.log(Math.abs(-10));
```

Comment: Ah sim, vou estudar sobre este comando, muito obrigado !!
O Math.mod estava dando erro x.x